# PHP - Run Function When Page Aborted

Tags: php, apache

I'm playing around with using `ini_set('ignore_user_abort', true/false);` to allow or disallow PHP scripts to continue running on the server even when the client has gone (i.e., navigated away from the page). When I set it to false, if the user navigates away, the script just instantly stops mid-execution. Is there any way to run a function before the script ends?

If the user navigates away, I basically want to gracefully close a couple of things and insert a record into a database.

Comment: navigates away and 'aborts' are not the same thing , if the scripts are finished, and the user navigates away that's a different thing than leaving while scripts are running. php being server-side, usually scripts are all finished before the user even sees the page.

Comment: The script is started after the page loads with ajax, it's like a 5 minute script, using TRUE it does continue to run even if the user closes the tab (tested)

Comment: well ajax, that's different, details in original question would **really** help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `ignore_user_abort` to `true`, and then use [`connection_aborted()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.connection-aborted.php) to check whether user has aborted. One possible place to check could be a [shutdown callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php).

Comment: I don't think that will work, because after the user aborts, the server aborts too and your code won't run.  Probably the best that can be done is a check of `connection_aborted()` just before deciding whether to tidy up and quit or continue processing.  There doesn't seem to be any way to register a callback function for an abort event.  (edited) saw your reply - never mind.

Comment: @JuanTomas No, with `ignore_user_abort` set to `true` the server shouldn't abort when the client does.

Comment: Okay, there it is in your edit.  `register_shutdown_function()`.  +1